# SWF flash files not loading with IIS compression on

Tags: flash, http, iis, iis-7, compression

I've got a bunch of flash files being served off a HTTPS site in IIS7. With content compression turned on, the flash files wont display. Does flash not support HTTP compression, or is IIS doing something unusual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume it is that SWF files are already compressed so most web servers do not compress them. If IIS7 is compressing them then the Flash Player will not know how to decompress them and they will not display.

You should not compress SWF files.

Comment: Yup, had to turn off static-file compression and my swf file played as expected.